# Can we call method having more than one arguments with list.map?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I was trying to perform multiply operation on list in Scala like:

```
  val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
  list.map(_*2)

  res0: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10) // Output
```

Now, I have created a separate method for the multiply operation like:

```
  val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
  def multiplyListContents(x: Int) = {
    x * 2
  } 

  list.map(multiplyListContents)

  res1: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10) // Output
```

Now I want to pass custom multiplier instead of using default multiplier `2` like:

```
  val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)

  val multiplier = 3

  def multiplyListContents(x: Int, multiplier: Int) = {
    x * multiplier
  } 

  list.map(multiplyListContents(multiplier))

  res1: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 9, 12, 15) // Output should be this
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scala> list.map(multiplyListContents(_, multiplier))
res0: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 9, 12, 15)
```

This translates to `list.map(x => multiplyListContents(x, multiplier))`.
(see `scala placeholder syntax` for more information).